# Recover "all null" XML file that Visual Studio corrupted?

Tags: xml, corruption

I was working on an XML file using Visual Studio when Windows crashed unexpectedly due to a known issue.

Now when I open the file, the 6KB of XML code has been replaced with 6KB of nothing but null characters. Everything I use to open it (including file recovery programs) seem to think it's a perfectly valid file, just full of nulls. Scandisk does nothing.

I'm thinking without a backup I'm pretty much up a creek, but I figured I'd see if anyone knew anything about this (my Google-fu failed me) before I spend a couple of hours rewriting the thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Yup. Without a backup (automatic or manual) you're up a creek *without* a paddle. (Now might be a good time to invest in Hg/Git/your-flavor-of-VCS.)

Comment: Did you already try going to Properties > Previous Versions?

Comment: The file's gone, give up and rebuild it.

Comment: Yeah, no dice. It sounds like this may be some sort of bizarre problem unique to me, I can't find a single reference of this happening to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, was waiting till the end of the day to commit my code, when suddenly, my file was replaced with all NULL characters. I have a feeling some other forensic file recovery packages would have the same effect, but i used Encase and the file was easily found and recovered..

Answer (score -1):

Check-out my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344290/lost-the-content-of-aspx-page-on-computer-restart-before-saving-the-file/16740939#16740939

NEXT TIME YOU WILL BE SAVED ... :D